# Partial derivation with respect to a difference

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative

I have the following function

$$f(\gamma,\kappa)=\gamma\kappa M^{2}(h_{v}+2(\kappa+\gamma M-\gamma)h_{\epsilon})(\kappa-\gamma)$$

What I want to know is how does $f(.)$ vary when $(\kappa-\gamma)$ changes.
What I'm thinking of is to find the partial derivation with respect to $(\kappa-\gamma)$:

$$\frac{\partial f(\gamma,\kappa)}{\partial(\kappa-\gamma)}=?$$

I am quite sure, i cannot just do the following:

$$\frac{\partial f(\gamma,\kappa)}{\partial(\kappa-\gamma)}=\gamma\kappa M^{2}(h_{v}+2(\kappa+\gamma M-\gamma)h_{\epsilon})$$
How can I solve this Problem?

Comment: So: $M$, $h_v$, and $h_{\epsilon}$ are constants? And the domain of $f$ is all pairs of real numbers?

Comment: Yes to both questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the only variables ar $\gamma$ and $\kappa$:
you must make a change of variables, for example:
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{c}
x=\gamma+\kappa\\
y=\kappa-\gamma
\end{array}
\right.
$$
Since $2\gamma=x-y$ and $2\kappa=x+y$, you can write
$$
g(x,y)=\frac{1}{4}(x+y)(x-y) M^{2}(h_{v}+2(y+\frac{x-y}{2} M)h_{\epsilon})y
$$
Now you can make the partial derivative of $g$ respect to $y$ and write again in the variables $\gamma$ and $\kappa$.